# using files in multiple functions with linked list

Tags: c++, file-io, linked-list

I am writing a simple "database" program that just uses text files. I first created the createDB function so that the user could name the file they wanted to create. To make sure the name was unique and there wasn't already a file with that name I put the name in a linked list. I use the linked list in my openDB function as well to make sure there is a file of that name to open. The problem I am having is each time the program starts the linked list is empty and I am wondering if there is anyway to make it keep its contents. So that I can create a file, close my program, then start the program and open that file again without creating a new one. Also if I put a file into my folder that is full with text, if I create a file and name it the same thing it just overwrites that file with a blank file and I don't know how to stop that. There is probably a better way to do all of this than a linked list and suggestions would be nice. Any help would be appreciated.

I just put all my code in here, there are still a lot of empty functions but I am only worried about the create and open ones as of now, thanky you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

class List{

private:
    struct dataB{ //node
        string name;
        int open; //1 if open 0 if closed
        dataB *next;
    };
    // initializing node variables to go through linked list and search
    dataB *head;
    dataB *curr;
    dataB *temp;

public:
    List();
    void insert(string name, int open);
    bool search(string fName);
    void createDB();
    void openDB();
    int menu();
}; //end class

List::List(){
    head = NULL;
    curr = NULL;
    temp = NULL;
}
void List::insert(string name, int open){
    dataB *n = new dataB;
    n->next = NULL;
    n->name = name;
    n->open = open;

    if(head != NULL){ // if already things in list put it last
        curr = head;
        while(curr->next != NULL){
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        curr->next = n; // always puts new node at the end
    }
    else{ // if no list, make new node the start of list
        head = n;
    }
}

bool List::search(string fName){ //return false if no match, true if there is
    curr = head; //start from beginning of list
    while(curr != NULL) {
        if (fName == curr->name){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


void List::createDB() {
    ofstream db;
    string fileName;

    cout << "Enter the name of the database you want to create: \n";
    getline (cin, fileName);

    if(this->search(fileName) == false){ // means new filename, create db
        db.open(fileName.c_str());
        cout << "\nYour database " << fileName << " was created successfully\n";
        this->insert(fileName, 0);
    }
    else{ // checking if the filename is taken
        cout << "\nCould not create database because database name " << fileName << " is already taken\n";
    }

    db.close();

}

void List::openDB() {
    // need to add check to see if one is already open
    ofstream db;
    string fileName;

    cout << "Enter the name of the database you want to open: \n";
    getline (cin, fileName);

    if(this->search(fileName) == false){ // means file not found
                cout << "\nThere is no database named " << fileName << " to open\n";
    }

    else{ // checking if there is a file of that name to open
        cout << "\nThe database " << fileName << " has been opened successfully\n";
        db.open(fileName.c_str());
        this->insert(fileName, 1);
    }
}

void closeDB() {

    cout << "The database _______ has been closed successfully";
}

void display() {
    cout << "Enter the ID of the employee you want to display: \n";
}

void update() {

}

void report() {

}

void add() {

}

void del() {

}

int List::menu() {
    cout << "Enter the number of the operation you wish to perform (1-9)\n"
    << "1. Create new database\n"
    << "2. Open database\n"
    << "3. Close database\n"
    << "4. Display record\n"
    << "5. Update record\n"
    << "6. Create report\n"
    << "7. Add a record\n"
    << "8. Delete a record\n"
    << "9. Quit\n";

    int sel = 0;
    (std::cin >> sel).ignore();

    switch (sel) {
        case 1: createDB();
            menu(); // after creating file go back to list of options
            break;

        case 2: openDB();
            menu();
            break;

        case 3: closeDB();
            menu();
            break;

        case 4: display();
            break;

        case 5: update();
            break;

        case 6: report();
            break;

        case 7: add();
            break;

        case 8: del();
            break;

        case 9: return 0;
            break;

        default: cout << "Please try again and enter a valid number\n\n";
            menu();
            break;
    }
    return true; // to avoid error saying control may reach end of non-void function
}


int main() {
    List list;
    list.menu();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you really wanted a linked list, why didn't you simply use `std::list` or `std::forward_list` so that you don't waste time trying to implement your own?

Answer (score -1):

You don't need the linked list in the first place. Just check whether the file exists *in the filesystem,* with `stat(2)` for example.